# Setting "CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Q: How to set "CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL" on/off using PostgreSQL?

**Example**: In SQL Server the syntax is:

```
 SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF/ON;
```

**Note**: Need to do same in PostgreSQL.

Comment: No idea what that is. Is it something like NULLIF?

Comment: @bma, If my query is: select 'xyz'|null then it should return xyz but not null. For this control I am trying to set concatenation result off.

Comment: @bma, NULLIF returns null value only and only if value1 and value2 are same. Which does not meet my query.

Comment: No, you can't configure Postgres that way. If you want a null safe string concatenation use `concat()` which treats a `null` value as an empty string.

Comment: `COALESCE()` is the function you should use generally, or `CONCAT()` in this specific case as suggested http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: You may also try select 'XYZ'||coalesce(null, '')::text; ==> 'XYZ';